# "org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The encoding "GBK" is not supported."

Tags: java, xml, character-encoding, xerces

```
Document dws;
    try {
        dws = XmlFactory.getResource("/com/newzhongway/service/test.xml");
        ExtDocument ext= new ExtDocument(dws);
        String rexml = XmlFactory.getXmlStr(dws);
        String jsonStr = Xml2JsonUtil.xml2JSON(rexml);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

myclipse get errors in **console**

```
org.jdom.input.JDOMParseException: Error on line 0: The encoding "GBK" is not supported.
at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:533)
at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:865)
at com.zhongway.pub.handler.Xml2JsonUtil.xml2JSON(Xml2JsonUtil.java:30)
at com.zhongway.pub.handler.Xml2JsonUtil.main(Xml2JsonUtil.java:214)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The encoding "GBK" is not supported.
at org.apache.xerces.framework.XMLParser.reportError(XMLParser.java:1196)
at org.apache.xerces.readers.DefaultEntityHandler.startReadingFromDocument(DefaultEntityHandler.java:541)
at org.apache.xerces.framework.XMLParser.parseSomeSetup(XMLParser.java:312)
at org.apache.xerces.framework.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:1080)
at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:518)
... 3 more
```

my xml file is

```
<?xml version='1.0'  encoding='gb2312'?>
         <interfacemsg>
           <query>
             <sheetNo>2015080700001</sheetNo>
             <DEALER>KEDA</DEALER>
             <PROV>sn_eoms</PROV>
           </query>
           <result>
             <sheetDetailInfo>
               <BasicInfo>
                 <WSID>2015080700001</WSID>
                 <WSTYPECODE>移动专业故障</WSTYPECODE>
                 <WSINFOHINT>移动网:CDMA网；故障对象:测试</WSINFOHINT>
                 <BEGINTIME>2015-08-07 08:45:01</BEGINTIME>
                 <ENDTIME></ENDTIME>
                 <STATUS>受理派单</STATUS>
                 <URGEDEGREE>一般</URGEDEGREE>
                 <PASTTIME>4734</PASTTIME>
               </BasicInfo>
               <handleInfoList>
                 <handleInfo>
                   <TASKNAME>申告工单</TASKNAME>
                   <TASKCREATETIME>2015-08-07 08:45:01</TASKCREATETIME>
                   <HANDLEPERSON>KEDA</HANDLEPERSON>
                   <TASKRECEIVETIME></TASKRECEIVETIME>
                   <HANDLETIME>2015-08-07 08:45:02</HANDLETIME>
                   <HANDLEDETAIL></HANDLEDETAIL>
                 </handleInfo>
                 <handleInfo>
                   <TASKNAME>受理派单</TASKNAME>
                   <TASKCREATETIME>2015-08-07 08:45:01</TASKCREATETIME>
                   <HANDLEPERSON></HANDLEPERSON>
                   <TASKRECEIVETIME></TASKRECEIVETIME>
                   <HANDLETIME></HANDLETIME>
                   <HANDLEDETAIL></HANDLEDETAIL>
                 </handleInfo>
               </handleInfoList>
               <applyInfo>
                 <CUSTTYPE></CUSTTYPE>
                 <APPLYER>KEDA</APPLYER>
                 <APPLYTIME>2015-08-07 08:45:00</APPLYTIME>
                 <APPLYUNIT>科大恒星</APPLYUNIT>
                 <TROUBLEOBJ>测试</TROUBLEOBJ>
                 <NETWORK>CDMA网</NETWORK>
                 <APPLYCLASS>国内漫游</APPLYCLASS>
                 <APPLYCLASSSMALL>语音业务</APPLYCLASSSMALL>
                 <TROUBLEDESCR>测试</TROUBLEDESCR>
                 <CCFXHJDCL>初步分析处理</CCFXHJDCL>
                 <IFINFLBUSI>否</IFINFLBUSI>
                 <HAPPENTIME>2015-08-07 03:00:00</HAPPENTIME>
                 <IFFIRSTFOUND>是</IFFIRSTFOUND>
                 <TROUBLESOURCE>其他</TROUBLESOURCE>
                 <TIMELIMIT></TIMELIMIT>
                 <CUSTLEVEL></CUSTLEVEL>
                 <GECUSTCLASS></GECUSTCLASS>
                 <CUSTINDUS></CUSTINDUS>
                 <CUSTSL></CUSTSL>
                 <CUSTLOCAL></CUSTLOCAL>
                 <OTHERCUSTINFO></OTHERCUSTINFO>
                 <ADDITIONALREMARK></ADDITIONALREMARK>
                 <ROAMINGTYPE></ROAMINGTYPE>
                 <ROAMINGCOUNTRY></ROAMINGCOUNTRY>
                 <IMSI></IMSI>
                 <CUSTNAME></CUSTNAME>
               </applyInfo>
               <dispatchInfoList/>
               <dealInfoList/>
               <hangupInfoList/>
               <callCenterInfoList/>
               <attachInfoList/>
               <OPList/>
             </sheetDetailInfo>
             <returnVal>
               <RETURN_CODE>0</RETURN_CODE>
               <RETURN_DESC>完成</RETURN_DESC>
             </returnVal>
           </result>
         </interfacemsg>
```

but why i have this error?
Can someone help me out what wrong with this code.
I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this

Comment: JDOM is not the "cause" of the problem, but it is reporting the symptom. The Xerces parser is compaining about the encoding. I have changed the tags on your question to reflect that. It looks like all your libraries, including the xerces parser (should be embeeded in JDK, not separate) and JDOM (should be `org.jdom2.*` and not `org.jdom.*`), is very old versions. Also, you need ot ensure that the GBK / GB2312 character/locale is installed on your machine.

Comment: Related: http://m.blog.csdn.net/article/details?id=46810189 - for me if I translate that to english it suggests similar fixes to my suggestions above - ensure your Java version and xerces versions are up to date. Note that recent Java versions have a built in recent xerces parser, and you don't need a xerces Jar file in your Jar path.